# Combine two csv into a single one with page breaks in python

Tags: python, csv

So I'm trying to combine two different csv files into a single one and I've done that. The two csv files are of students in school who are present in 1 and absent in another.
I need to put the date the file was created at the top of the new csv and have each grade of the present students on a new page or after 3 blank rows.
Also on each new page or after each 3 blanks i want to have the name or the teacher, the date on which the file was created and the grade.

```
 import csv
 with open('inschool.csv', encoding="cp437") as f:
     reader =  csv.reader(f)
     in_school = list(reader)
 with open('notinschool.csv', encoding="cp437") as f:
     reader =  csv.reader(f)
     not_in_school = list(reader)

 for grade, name, status, hr_teacher in not_in_school:
     print(grade, name, status, hr_teacher)
 for grade, name, status, hr_teacher in in_school:
     print(grade, name, status, hr_teacher)


 iFile = open('inschool.csv', encoding="cp437")
 reader = csv.reader(iFile)
 IFILE = open('notinschool.csv', encoding="cp437")
 READER = csv.reader(IFILE)
 oFile = open('combined.csv','wt',encoding="cp437")
 writer = csv.writer(oFile, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

 for row in READER:
    writer.writerow(row)
    writer.writerow("[]")
 for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)
    writer.writerow("[]")
```

The code which i tried for the 3 blank rows had this ending but it gave 3 blank rows/lines after each students name instead of after each grade.

```
iFile = open('Inschool.csv',)
reader = csv.reader(iFile)
IFILE = open('notinschool.csv')
READER = csv.reader(IFILE)
oFile = open('combined.csv','wb')
writer_a = csv.writer(oFile, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
writer_b = csv.writer(oFile, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, lineterminator="\n\n\n\n")

for row in READER:
   writer_a.writerow(row)

   writer_b.writerow([])

for row in reader:
   writer_b.writerow(row)
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me. Thanks.

Comment: csv files don't have the concept of "pages" or "page breaks". Could you expand on the process you intend to use to convert the csv file to pages?

Comment: @Robᵩ If not a page break, 3 lines between each grade would be pretty helpful too.  I edited the question and added additional code to elaborate more too now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it really easy in the terminal. Just `cd` to the directory and do the command `cat inschool.csv notinschool.csv > combined.csv`

If you want to do it in `Python` I would do:

```
in_file1 = open("inschool.csv","r").read().split("\n")
in_file2 = open("notinschool.csv","r").read().split("\n")

out_file = open("combined.csv","w")

for line in in_file1:
    if line:
        out_file.write(line + "\n")

for line in in_file2:
    if line: 
        out_file.write(line + "\n")
```

reading files the way above isn't the most efficient, but if they are small it doesnt really matter and it's easier to visualize what's happening. you can use your input file method with this b/c the concept stays the same :)

I just got into using this module called `pandas` and it is for `DataFrames`.  They are much easier to use, process, navigate through, and merge than parsing text files.

Comment: This code was able to add a line between the two different csv but didn't solve the 3 rows/ lines after each grade problem. Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: if they are empty lines, you can do `if line:` which checks if they have the good stuff.  check the update i made

Comment: For example, I have grade 10, 11 and 12. I want lines after the 10 values of each grade. Meaning; 10 grade 10 values then 3 blank lines then 10 grade 11 values and so on. Would appreciate your help

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file?

Comment: sooo, any ideas? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ehiz3FM5a9VTRVbmktQ3BxNjA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try making a for-loop where you iterate through all the teachers name and then write the name to a file, write 3*"\n" line breaks, write the contents of file.